# Use OpenMP with Windows SDK

Tags: winapi, openmp

I am aware that VC2010 Express Edition does not include OpenMP support and therefore would report omp.h file missing. Therefore, I have installed Windows SDK v7.1 64-bit version in Windows. However, even I ran:

```
set DISTUTIL_USE_SDK=1
setenv /x64 /release
```

And then try to compile the code, it would still report cannot find omp.h. Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you building from the command line or from VS?  If you're building from VS, you'll need to add the Windows SDK headers & libs to the include paths (Tools/Options/Projects & Solutions/VC++ Directories).

Comment: @EricBrown From the command line. I am actually using Cython in case you are familiar with it... It is essentially calling `cl` from the command line.

Comment: @EricBrown And also, I searched the SDK folder and did not find omp.h... OpenMP support seems to be not shipped with it, is that true?

Comment: The express edition of MSVC2012 and MSVC2013 both support OpenMP (It's what I use).  I have not found any official documentation on this but if you download either of them you will discover this.

Comment: @Zboson I thought that Python 3.3 will need MSC v1600, which is the version that compiled the CPython itself. I do have MSVC2012 installed but I do not know how to set Python to work with MSVC that is not VC2010 though...

Comment: @ShawnWang.  I don't know.  I don't use python now.

Answer (score 2):

Did some checking, and it appears that OpenMP is not part of the Windows SDK, and is only shipped with Visual C++ 2010 [Professional or Ultimate editions](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/).

Comment: The express edition of MSVC2012 and MSVC2013 both support OpenMP.

Comment: @shawn-wang Sounds like it's time to upgrade, then. :)

Comment: @EricBrown Well, but python 3.3 was compiled with MSVC 1600 which is vc2010... how do we tell cython to use later versions of msvc? I tried but did not find any config files to do it...

Comment: Doesn't cython come with makefiles?  Rebuilding cython from source _shouldn't_ be that hard...