# Cython memoryviews on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cython

When trying to use Cython on Windows (Anaconda-based install, using TDM-GCC as I need support for OpenMP), I ran into an error when using typed memoryviews.

```
test1.pyx
def test(int x): pass

test2.pyx
def test(int[:] x): pass
```

Both modules can be compiled with a basic setup.py (using cythonize), but while test1 can be imported with no problem, importing test2 raises the following:

```
python3 -c "import test2" (<- Note the use of Python3 -- I haven't tried with Python2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "stringsource", line 275, in init test2 (test2.c:13146)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte in position 1: invalid start byte.
```

with nothing special at line 13146 of test.c, apparently.

Is this a known issue?  Or am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be welcome.

(crossposted from Cython-users)

**Clarifications:**

- Again, please note that I am using Python 3 (In fact, the bug doesn't appear with Python 2).
- I am using a clean install into a Conda environment, using Python 3.4.1 and Cython 0.20.1.
- I am using the following setup.py.

  `from distutils.core import setup; from Cython.Build import cythonize`
  `setup(ext_modules=cythonize("test.pyx"))`

but a longer setup.py such as the one suggested by Saullo Castro doesn't help either.

**Bounty** awarded to Saullo Castro for pointing out that MinGW-64bit is not simply supported, even though I ended up using a different solution.

Comment: Can you post the Cython version? Then we can regenerate the C file and see what's at line 13146.

Comment: I got the same problem happening with TDM-GCC, but this goes away if I use MSVC. Well... probably a compatibility problem of GCC to MSVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7.5 64 bit and Cython 0.20.1 and your code works for me.

I tested your original code and this:

```
def test(int[:] x):
    s = np.shape(x)[0]
    for i in range(s):
        print x[i]
```

without problems. I will describe here how I compiled by Cython and how I configured my C compiler to use with Cython with the hope that you can solve your problem following these steps.

- Download and Microsoft SDK C Compiler [according to your Python version](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows)
- Configure your compiling environment in Windows, for me it is:

```
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
setenv /x64 /release
```

- Compile Cython (simply doing `python setup.py` should work)
- Have a nice `setup.py` for your `.pyx` files, here it follows a sample that I use to enable support to **OpenMP**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [Extension('test1',
                         ['test1.pyx'],
                         extra_compile_args=['/openmp', '/O2',
                                             '/favor:INTEL64'])]
setup(name = 'test1',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

- use `import pyximport; pyximport.install()` when applicable

Comment: I haven't tried with the Microsoft SDK, and I believe that the fact that I use python3 is more significant, as I don't see any error in python2 using TDM-GCC.  I have also tried your setup.py (without the extra_compile_args) and it doesn't help.

Comment: @antony the SDK is the official compiler and if you are on 64 bit [this compiler required](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows)

Comment: @SaulloCastro I guess antony might be sticking with GCC because the OpenMP support for VC 2010 or 2008 is not free. They are only in the non-express versions.

Comment: @ShawnWang but I use SDK with OpenMP support from the [link given by the Cython developers](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows)

Comment: @SaulloCastro I thought no from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935748/use-openmp-with-windows-sdk   could you please inform us how...?

Comment: @ShawnWang you are right... the SDK 7.0 recommended for Python 2.7 and Windows 7 64-Bit does not come with `omp.h`, therefore I installed the Visual Studio 2010 Express which comes with this package and is free, then I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Include` to the `INCLUDE` environment variable

Comment: @SaulloCastro but.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t(v=vs.100).aspx  This page at the bottom said VS2010 Express does not come with OpenMP support... :( *confused* Do you mean to say VS2010 Professional?

Comment: @ShawnWang I checked and I don't have the Professional. The OpenMP library is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include`, which corresponds to VS2008 actually... the OpenMP comes with some of the x86 redistributables in my case

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks for checking! http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c45672d-75af-4f32-bd10-20f7e3e30f39/visual-studio-2008-openmp-support   Actually, I wonder whether it's coming from some old installations of the Professional version, or it might be a problem of x86 vs x64. Well, in any case, thanks for discussing and checking back and forth with me :)

Comment: OK, so if I got this correctly, I cannot use OpenMP with a free version of VC2010 but could somehow work around it if I use some older version?
@SaulloCastro Can you clarify what is your exact setup?  Thanks.

Comment: @antony after this discussion with Shawn Wang I found out that it works for me because I installed a trial version of the Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 32 bit which comes with `omp.h, vcomp.lib and vcompd.lib`, required to use OpenMP, then I added the corresponding path to the `INCLUDE` environment variable

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the simplest solution was just to switch everything to 32bit, as TDM-GCC 32bit works fine and I don't have any hard dependencies on 64bit-Python.

Comment: +1 but I would keep trying with the 64bit version :)

Comment: @SaulloCastro Really thank you for your input and discussion... And I totally agree. I'd keep my fingers crossed so that one day 64 bit can work as well :) BTW, antony, I got a post here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cython-users/IHqn8QokZo8   and I will update here if a solution comes out eventually!