# Using Cython with the Microsoft SDK

Tags: windows, cython

I have been trying to get Cython to work on a 64 bit Windows 7 box.  First, I tried to use MinGW but ran into one problem after another.  After getting frustrated, I uninstalled MinGW and reversed all of my changes and decided to try using the Microsoft SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

First I installed the SDK, and then I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express.  After that, I used the Windows SDK Configuration Tool to set v7.0 as the current version.

I launched the SDK Command Prompt and set some environmental variables:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0>set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0>SetEnv.cmd /x64 /release
```

Still in the SDK Command Prompt, I tried to run the Cython Basic Tutorial:

```
C:\Users\spearsc\Documents\python_projects\test_cython>python setup.py build_ext
 --inplace
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\python27\include -IC:\python27\PC -c hellowo
rld.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\helloworld.o
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

I am surprised at this result because I thought gcc would not be used if I ran that command in the SDK Command Prompt.  Any idea what caused this error?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187702/832621) may serve you