# Missing vcvarsall.bat file

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, numpy, cython

I downloaded numpy package, created path for it in windows command. When I run

```
python setup.py install
```

command, then it returns an error like this:
[image: missing bat file]
How can I fix this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Hold on, I edited this question. Please check again

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Click the link in my report comment, and read that. It's the solution to your problem :)

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, I've VS 2012 express

Comment: @aerobit: Yeah, will check

Comment: @AjayKulkarni please, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187702/832621), I believe it will help you out...

Comment: Are you sure you want to compile Numpy yourself instead of using Winpython, Python(x,y) or Gohlke's binaries?

Comment: I want to compile numpy myself