# matlab mex cannot find vcomp.lib when openmp is used

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, mex

I am trying to mex a c++ source file containing `openmp` usages. In the mex command, i have added `COMPFLAGS="/openmp $COMPFLAGS"` but it says cannot find `vcomp.lib`. My matlab mex have been setup to use the compiler of Windows SDK 7.1 located in `C:\Program Files`. I checked the lib files inside this SDK and didn't find `vcomp.lib`. Anyone knows how can I install `openmp` to Windows SDK 7.1? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also have visual studio 2013 installed and I do find a file named `vcomp.lib` in its directory. Hence, I think perhaps I need to install something to Windows SDK 7.1 to make it have the `vcomp.lib` file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935748/use-openmp-with-windows-sdk), it seems openmp is not shipped with Windows SDK. It is only shipped with Visual Studion Professional or Ultimate.

This [matlab central site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44408-matlab-mex-support-for-visual-studio-2013--and-mbuild-) proposed a method to enable the matlab mex to use the Visual Studio 2013 compiler instead of the Windows SDK compiler. OpenMP is shipped with Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I can now compile code with OpenMp Enabled!